# Update Internet Explorer to newer version or not?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Is it recommended to replace (install through windows update) IE8 to IE9 in Windows7? Does it really entirely replace IE to newer version a on given system? (also Windows Explorer and all core files?). It seems that IE is tightly integrated with the system. I don't know that I should install IE9 or cumulative updates for IE8 - which method do you use and which brings less trouble? I don't use Internet Explorer as my main browser; I'm not that insane. I'm just curious that does Windows Update only installs update for browser but core files are kept the same, or it completely replaces IE to newest version?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a good reason to postpone the update (such as intranet site that will not work in newer version) it's always a good idea to upgrade. Microsoft is catching up in browser race and improvements between versions are quite big.

Comment: So, I should install IE9 rather than all these cumulative updates and fixes for IE8?

Comment: Yes, all those patches only fix stuff that isn't working right in IE8 (and are considered a bug by Microsoft). IE9 brings major changes that go way beyond bugfixes. You can also consider switching browser - nice browser comparison http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/windows-7-chrome-20-firefox-13-opera-12,3228-2.html

Comment: I think you didn't read my question carefully.

Comment: I did read it. Windows 7 still is a flagship Microsoft OS - IE9 update had been prepared for this system first and others later (priority-wise) and upgrade will be close to perfect no need to worry here. So go and install IE9 as it fixes many things that are wrong with IE8, not just IE8 bugs.